# Little doubt about the notation $\min(A)$ where A is a set

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

Sets can have minimal and least elements, and they are two different things, for example:
given the set $A=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ and the subset relation, this set has $\{1\}$ as a minimal element but not as a least element. Now, my question is, what is $\min(A)$? I would say that it doesn't exists since there are not least elements, but does $\min(A)$ really mean "least element of the set $A$"? I'm asking because the notation "$\min$" looks like it's referring to the minimal element and not the least one. And is this notation really referring to the least element of a set or instead it's a completely different things and we're talking about a unary operation used for the natural numbers, integers and real numbers?

Comment: I assume you mean $a\lt b\iff a\subset b$. In which case this set has no minimum but has infimum $\{\}$.

Comment: I think that $\min$ is a short of "minimum", rather than of "minimal".

Comment: @AsafKaragila oh yeah of course! I was not thinking about it, least element and minimum element are the same things, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, $\min(A)$ is used in the context of a linear order (so all elements are comparable), and it means "minimum" (so the (unique) least element). I've never seen it used for "minimal element(s)" of a poset.

So your set $A$ has 3 minimal elements (the singletons), but no minimum indeed.

If you're using a textbook (or lecture notes of some kind), the notation $\min(A)$ should have been defined, but for me, when I see $\min(A)$ I assume implicitly that $A$ is linearly ordered and has a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

For all academic intent and purposes, **Henno Brandsma's answer is the one I recommend**. However, every time I get the opportunity to discuss this one peculiar natural correspondence between finitary sets and natural numbers I jump on it like a shark! It goes like this:

For any set, its integer equivalence is defined (meta-mathematically) by

$$S=\sum_{x\in S}2^x$$

(Note: $2^x$ is basic exponentiation, rather than the ambiguous notation for the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).)

The reason I bring this up here is because, unlike the [Von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals), it allows any finite set (of finite rank) to uniquely correspond to an integer. What this means for us is that all elements within $A$, can be rewritten into integers. Hence $\min(A)$ actually makes sense in this strange system.

$$A=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$$
$$\implies A=\{(2^1),(2^2),(2^3),(2^1+2^2),(2^2+2^3),(2^1+2^3),(2^1+2^2+2^3)\}$$
$$\implies A=\{2,4,8,6,12,10,14\}$$
$$\implies \min(A)=2=\{1\}$$

Application wise, this system draws it's roots from $p$-adic systems similar to the ones in Andrew Wile's famous proof of Fermat's Last theorem; so it does have some import.